# Family finances - tracking and reporting

Tags: java, hash-map

I am looking for clean way to accumulate amounts within a input dataset.  In this example, there are 18 rows of data, and the output is a 3 rows of data, accumulated by Key, by ExpenseType.

My biggest concern is whether hashMap is the correct utility for this, or if there is an easier/cleaner way.

FamilyExpenseProcessor.java:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class FamilyExpenseProcessor {

    enum ExpenseType {
        Grocery, Entertainment,Transportation
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, FamilyExpense> feHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(5.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(10.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(15.00));

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(20.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(25.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(30.00));

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(35.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(40.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(45.00));

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(50.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(55.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Grocery, new BigDecimal(60.00));

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(15.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(20.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(25.00));

        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons",ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(30.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(35.00));
        accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Transportation, new BigDecimal(40.00));

        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, FamilyExpense>> entries = feHashMap.entrySet()
                .iterator();

        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, FamilyExpense> entry = entries.next();
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Grocery = "
                    + entry.getValue().getGroceryExpense());
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Entertainment = "
                    + entry.getValue().getEntertainmentExpense());
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Transportation = "
                    + entry.getValue().getTransportationExpense());
        }

    }

    private static void accumulate(Map<String, FamilyExpense> feMap,
            String key, ExpenseType expenseType, BigDecimal value) {

        switch (expenseType) {
        case Grocery:

            if (feMap.containsKey(key)) {
                feMap.get(key).setGroceryExpense(
                        feMap.get(key).getGroceryExpense().add(value));
            } else {

                FamilyExpense fe = new FamilyExpense();
                fe.setGroceryExpense(value);
                feMap.put(key, fe);
            }
            break;
        case Entertainment:

            if (feMap.containsKey(key)) {
                feMap.get(key).setEntertainmentExpense(
                        feMap.get(key).getEntertainmentExpense().add(value));
            } else {

                FamilyExpense fe = new FamilyExpense();
                fe.setEntertainmentExpense(value);
                feMap.put(key, fe);
            }
            break;
        case Transportation:

            if (feMap.containsKey(key)) {
                feMap.get(key).setTransportationExpense(
                        feMap.get(key).getTransportationExpense().add(value));
            } else {

                FamilyExpense fe = new FamilyExpense();
                fe.setTransportationExpense(value);
                feMap.put(key, fe);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

FamilyExpense.java:

```
 import java.math.BigDecimal;

 class FamilyExpense {

    private String familyId;
    private BigDecimal groceryExpense;
    private BigDecimal entertainmentExpense;
    private BigDecimal transportationExpense;

    public FamilyExpense(){
        this.groceryExpense = new BigDecimal(0);
        this.transportationExpense = new BigDecimal(0);
        this.entertainmentExpense = new BigDecimal(0);

    }
    public String getFamilyId() {
        return familyId;
    }

    public void setFamilyId(String familyId) {
        this.familyId = familyId;
    }

    public BigDecimal getGroceryExpense() {


        return groceryExpense;
    }

    public void setGroceryExpense(BigDecimal groceryExpense) {
        this.groceryExpense = groceryExpense;
    }

    public BigDecimal getEntertainmentExpense() {

        return this.entertainmentExpense;
    }

    public void setEntertainmentExpense(BigDecimal entertainmentExpense) {
        this.entertainmentExpense = entertainmentExpense;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTransportationExpense() {
        return transportationExpense;
    }

    public void setTransportationExpense(BigDecimal transportationExpense) {
        this.transportationExpense = transportationExpense;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have changed your code a bit to make it cleaner.It is recommended to have a uniform interface for methods, so now you have two methods in FamilyExpense class is **addExpense** and another is **getExpense** rather explicitly calling each method.

I am not sure why you have used getFamilyId and setFamilyId.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, FamilyExpense> feHashMap = new HashMap<String, FamilyExpense>();
    feHashMap.put("Jeffersons", new FamilyExpense());
    feHashMap.put("Jetsons", new FamilyExpense());
    feHashMap.put("Johnsons", new FamilyExpense());

    accumulate(feHashMap, "Jeffersons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(5.00));
    accumulate(feHashMap, "Jetsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(10.00));
    accumulate(feHashMap, "Johnsons", ExpenseType.Entertainment, new BigDecimal(10.00));


    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, FamilyExpense>> entries = feHashMap.entrySet()
            .iterator();

    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, FamilyExpense> entry = entries.next();
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Grocery = "
                + entry.getValue().getExpense(ExpenseType.Grocery));
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Entertainment = "
                + entry.getValue().getExpense(ExpenseType.Entertainment));
        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Transportation = "
                + entry.getValue().getExpense(ExpenseType.Transportation));
    }

}

 public static void accumulate(Map<String, FamilyExpense> feMap,
                              String key, ExpenseType expenseType, BigDecimal value) {

    FamilyExpense familyExpense=null;

    if(feMap.containsKey(key)){
        familyExpense=feMap.get(key);
        familyExpense.addExpense(value,expenseType);
    }
    else{
        FamilyExpense newFamily = new FamilyExpense();
        newFamily.addExpense(value,expenseType);
        feMap.put(key,newFamily);
    }
}
```

This is your family expense class.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class FamilyExpense {

private String familyId;
private BigDecimal groceryExpense;
private BigDecimal entertainmentExpense;
private BigDecimal transportationExpense;

public FamilyExpense(){
    this.groceryExpense = new BigDecimal(0);
    this.transportationExpense = new BigDecimal(0);
    this.entertainmentExpense = new BigDecimal(0);
}

public BigDecimal getExpense(FamilyExpenseProcessor.ExpenseType expenseType){
    switch (expenseType){
        case Entertainment:
            return this.entertainmentExpense;
        case Grocery:
            return this.groceryExpense;
        case Transportation:
            return this.transportationExpense;
        default:
            return new BigDecimal(0.0);
    }
}

public void addExpense(BigDecimal expense, FamilyExpenseProcessor.ExpenseType expenseType){
    switch (expenseType){
        case Entertainment:
            this.entertainmentExpense=this.entertainmentExpense.add(expense);
            break;
        case Grocery:
            this.groceryExpense=groceryExpense.add(expense);
            break;
        case Transportation:
            this.transportationExpense=this.transportationExpense.add(expense);
            break;
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest adding a method `addExpense(ExpenseType expenseType, BigDecimal amount)` to `FamilyExpense`. That way your `accumulate` method could look like this:

```
private static void accumulate(Map<String, FamilyExpense> expenses, String key, ExpenseType expenseType, BigDecimal amount) {
  if (expenses.containsKey(key)) {
    expenses.get(key).addExpense(expenseType, amount);
    return;
  }

  FamilyExpense expense =  new FamilyExpense();
  expense.addExpense(expenseType, amount);
  expenses.put(key, expense);
}
```

You can also iterate through the entries using `entrySet`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, FamilyExpense> entry : entries.entrySet()) {
  ...
}
```